# System.Data.SqlClientを使用した更新処理が行えない

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server

環境
Visual Studio Express for Desktop
SQL Server Express 2014
C# Windows Form アプリケーション

にて開発を行っております。
レコードの更新を行おうとした所エラーは発生しないものの、レコードの更新も行われない状態となりました。

以下がコードとなります(例外は通っていないためcatchは省略しています)
また、同様のコネクションを作成し、INSERT文では同様にレコードの追加が行われませんでしたが、SELECT文を発行するとそちらに関しては正常に結果が取得できました。
問題点が特定出来ないため何かお気づきの点があればよろしくお願いいたします。

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;"
                       +       @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;"
                       + "Database=dbo;"
                       + "integrated security=true";
con.Open();
try
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE table_name SET foo = 'bar' WHERE id = 1 ", con);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: `TransactionScope`などの効果でロールバックされているのでは？

Comment: pgrhoさま
ご回答頂きありがとうございます。

TransactionScopeについて調べてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;"
```

とのことですが、ビルドする度に `test.mdf` を上書きしていませんか？

もしくは実際に書き込みを行った `test.mdf` と別のディレクトリに保存されている `test.mdf` に対して更新されたかどうかを確認していませんか？ 前者は`|DataDirectory|`ですので既定では実行ファイルと同じディレクトリです。

---

ソリューションエクスプローラーで`test.mdf`のプロパティを確認すると分かりますが、チュートリアルの方法では既定で「常にコピーする」になっており、プロジェクトディレクトリにある`test.mdf`がビルド出力先（実行ファイルと同じディレクトリ）へコピーされます。

なお、プログラムは上記の通りコピー先（実行ファイルと同じディレクトリ）の`test.mdf`を参照しますが、同チュートリアルのデータベースエクスプローラーで接続しているのはコピー元（プロジェクトディレクトリ）の`test.mdf`です。つまり、上記指摘の両方の間違いを犯しています。

Comment: sayuriさま

ご回答頂きありがとうございます。

設定等は変更していないのですがその状態ですとビルドするたびにmdfが上書きされるような動作になるのでしょうか？

確認しました所書き込もうとしたmdfと保存先は合っているようでした。

DB作成手順としては下記の「Customers テーブルを作成するには」
までを参考に行いました。

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms233763.aspx

Comment: @eos さん、回答を更新しました。

Comment: @sayuriさま
実行ファイルのディレクトリとプロジェクトディレクトリを履き違えておりました。失礼致しました。
実行ファイルのディレクトリにmdfが作成されることが確認でき、プロパティについても変更しました。別のエラーで少し時間を取ってしまい動作確認が後になってしまいますが確認次第この質問を解決とさせていただきたいと思います。

Comment: @sayuriさま 無事更新データの確認が出来ました。ありがとうございます。解決とさせて頂きます。